# Google Drive API: 4-5% 500 server error rate for conversions (V3)

Tags: google-drive-api

We recently upgraded to V3, and we get a 4-5% 500 server error rate for file conversions to google documents or pdfs. We experience this problem using the iOS SDK, but I doubt this problem is iOS specific.

Files can be converted in two different ways and both approaches can fail with a 500 error. If the source file on google drive is already a google document, we use files.export to download a pdf. If the source file isn't a google document, we use files.copy to convert it first to a document, then download it using files.export.

We were able to determine that only certain files fail to convert and they fail consistently. What's weird is that I successfully converted them using the API with another google drive project. The files also convert fine using google drive itself (though the web browser). This makes me think it could be some sort of throttling, but here are only 2 requests per second for the export endpoint, nothing crazy (though we do have a much higher overall request rate). I'm not sure exponential backoff is applicable in this case, as it fails immediately and consistently for specific files. This isn't a server process, conversions are generated on-demand by our users.

Note that I'm aware that some files *cannot* be converted by google. These files fail even through google drive in the web browser. In this case, the files used to convert fine in V2.

Any ideas?

I created an issue: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5201

I have sample files that fail to convert, but I can't post them publicly. If someone from google is interested, I can email you sample files. Find me through the issue above.

**EDIT 03/06/2017**

I was able to reproduce the problem with the python SDK. Converting a specific file using the copy operation like this:

```
service.files().copy(fileId="0B7LfP9ECyCHpOEhseWlUd3FtZVk", body = {"mimeType" : "application/vnd.google-apps.document"}).execute()
```

Consistently fail for my current client ID with this error:

```
{'status': '500', 'content-length': '52', 'x-xss-protection': '1;mode=block', 
'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 
'chunked', 'expires': 'Mon, 06 Mar 2017 17:24:15 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, 
X-Origin', 'server': 'GSE', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 
'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Mon, 06 Mar 2017 17:24:15 GMT', 'xframe-options': 
'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34"', 'content-type': 
'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

{"error": {"code": 500,"message": null}}
```

But then succeeds when I use a newly created client ID.

Comment: Does the "another google drive project" use the same code implementation as your current project which is getting the 4-5% error?

Comment: @noogui Yes. I was also able to reproduce the problem in python with a single request. See edits.